# transform .SVG images by the help of PHP - Image Magick similar

Tags: php, image, svg, imagemagick, transformation

There's a need to transform .svg files and save em either in .svg or jpeg format. The problems with ImageMagick is that it saves transformed files on white background and I deadly need it on transparent.

Any suggestions with other tools or clear php? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: JPEG doesn't support transparency.

Comment: What transformation do you actually need to do to the SVG files?

Answer (score 4):

The right ImageMagick command should be:

```
convert -background none somefile.svg somefile.png
```

You should use PNG or GIF as file format, because JPEG doesn't support transparency.

To use it in PHP:

```
<?php
$svg_file_name = "somefile.svg";
$png_file_name = "somefile.png;
system("convert -background none $svg_file_name $png_file_name");
?>
```

Comment: you said "Any suggestions with other tools or clear php", so it was with some other tool! But you can call this from within PHP, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can transform SVG files easily from within php. SVG files are basically XML files, and the standard is public, so anyone can make a converter...

I'd go for the external tool, it's easier and faster than processing from within a scripted language, and a lot safer when the author of the script dosen't actually know how to find out the command line switches for an application, and that JPEG files does not support transparency:)

go for `convert -background none somefile.svg somefile.png` as Jens said...

Answer (score 0):

You can't do transparency with JPEG, but here's how to save an SVG as a PNG with a transparent background...

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent')); 
$image->readImage('somefile.svg');

// ... do any image manipulation you need to here ... 

$image->setImageFormat('png32');
$image->writeImage('somefile.png');
```